# Google Ad Manager Integration -> Unmarshalling Error: cvc-type.2: The type definition cannot be abstract for element children

Tags: integration, soap, google

We are trying to build an integration from Salesforce to Google Ad Manager, using the Google Ad Manager ForecastService API : https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202205/ForecastService#getAvailabilityForecastById

We used Salesforce's out of the box functionality for generating a SOAP class based on the WSDL.

I sucessfully built an integration with Google Ad Manager: using APEX to get a token and then calling the generated classes and methods to getting the AvailabilityForecast from a lineItem in Google Ad Manager.
However, I encountered an issue when trying to use the getAvailabilityForecastById method and providing customTargeting. It is important to note that I was able to get a callout result when prividing inventoryTargeting, so the problem I have is only for Custom Targeting.

As I said, we have sucessfully defined the following classes and generated code based on them , to process our sample scenario:

getAvailabilityForecastById => ForecastBreakdownOptions =>  ForecastBreakdownTarget[] => Targeting

The following ar the classes that we have adjusted in Salesforce in order to satisfy the CustomCriteriaSet children attribute, which requires a CustomCriteriaNode[], populated with either CustomCriteriaSet or CustomCriteria objects:

```
public abstract class CustomCriteriaNode {
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202302','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
}



public virtual class CustomCriteriaSet extends CustomCriteriaNode{
    public String logicalOperator;
    public ForecastService.CustomCriteriaNode[] children;
    private String[] logicalOperator_type_info = new String[]{'logicalOperator','https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202302',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] children_type_info = new String[]{'children','https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202302',null,'0','-1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202302','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'logicalOperator','children'};
}

public abstract class CustomCriteriaLeaf extends CustomCriteriaNode{
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202302','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
}


public class CustomCriteria extends CustomCriteriaLeaf{
    public Long keyId;
    public Long[] valueIds;
    public String operator;
    private String[] keyId_type_info = new String[]{'keyId','https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202302',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] valueIds_type_info = new String[]{'valueIds','https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202302',null,'0','-1','false'};
    private String[] operator_type_info = new String[]{'operator','https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202302',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v202302','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'keyId','valueIds','operator'};
}

____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________




ForecastService.CustomCriteria criteria = new ForecastService.CustomCriteria();
criteria.keyId = 1234L;
criteria.valueIds = new List<Long>{5678L};
criteria.operator = 'IS';



ForecastService.CustomCriteriaSet customTargetingLevel2 = new ForecastService.CustomCriteriaSet();
customTargetingLevel2.logicalOperator = 'OR';
customTargetingLevel2.children = new List<ForecastService.CustomCriteriaNode>{criteria};



ForecastService.CustomCriteriaSet customTargeting = new ForecastService.CustomCriteriaSet();
customTargeting.logicalOperator = 'OR';
customTargeting.children =  new List<ForecastService.CustomCriteriaNode>{customTargetingLevel2};


ForecastService.Targeting targeting = new ForecastService.Targeting();
//targeting.inventoryTargeting = inventoryTargeting;
targeting.customTargeting = customTargeting;


ForecastService.ForecastBreakdownTarget breakdownTarget = new ForecastService.ForecastBreakdownTarget();
breakdownTarget.targeting = targeting;

List<ForecastService.ForecastBreakdownTarget> targets = new List<ForecastService.ForecastBreakdownTarget>{breakdownTarget};

ForecastService.ForecastBreakdownOptions breakdownOptions = new ForecastService.ForecastBreakdownOptions();
breakdownOptions.targets = targets;

ForecastService.AvailabilityForecastOptions forecastOptions = new ForecastService.AvailabilityForecastOptions();
forecastOptions.includeTargetingCriteriaBreakdown = false;
forecastOptions.includeContendingLineItems = false;
forecastOptions.breakdown = breakdownOptions;

// Make the API call
ForecastService.AvailabilityForecast res = api.getAvailabilityForecastById(lineItemId,forecastOptions);

System.debug(JSON.serialize(res));
```

The callout error that we get in this scenario is
**"Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Unmarshalling Error: cvc-type.2: The type definition cannot be abstract for element children.  faultcode=soap:Client faultactor="**
I have tried a lot of things, searched online a lot, but nothing seems to work. Any feedback would be greately appreciated! Thank you !